# android location aware activity recognition issue

Tags: android, android-activity, location

Greetings.

I have compiled and run the activity recognition code from the following link
http://developer.android.com/training/location/activity-recognition.html

It is not working properly. When i was inside my house it says
on_vehicle with confidence 36
on_bicycle with confidence 3

I have checked this on micromax canvas with ICS

The google documentation doesn't' mention the hardware/sensor support required for this
feature.

Please let me know what are the hardware/sensor support required for this feature.

Best Regards
jothi

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/DetectedActivity.html) for the confidence implies that anything below 50 really is not very good.  I think you will need to put your own wrapper around things.  It will then probably be rather phone specific, I would be looking at a user set-able threshold of some sort.